# Making a sub model an IEnumerable in my ViewModel in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I am trying to setup a ViewModel - one that includes two DropDown Lists.

**RatesList** has a **"ValueRange"** dropdown list, which works fine.

I also want it to have an **"Occ"** dropdown list - currently it's just a nested model - but I need it to be an IEnumerable so I can use an EditorTemplate to display Occs, within the Rates EditorTemplate.

My two models are:

```
 public class RatesList
{
    [Key]
    public long TypeID { get; set; }
    public int NumSelected { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ValueRange
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, this.TypeCount + 1)
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.ToString(),
                    Text = x.ToString()
                });
        }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<Occ> Occs { get; set; }
    public string OccSelected { get; set; }

}
```

...and...

```
public class Occ
{
    public string occdesc { get; set; }
    public string curr { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string OccSelected { get; set; }
    public string occval
    {
        get
        {
            return occdesc + "||" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", ratetocharge) + "||" + TypeName;
        }
    }
    public string occdesc2
    {
        get
        {
            return occdesc + " (" + curr + string.Format("{0:0.00}", ratetocharge) + ")  ";
        }
    }
    public decimal ratetocharge { get; set; }
    public virtual RatesList RatesList { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway I can do what I'm asking within a viewmodel - ie. have Occ as an IEnumerable/SelectList within the RatesList ViewModel?

Thanks for any help, Mark

Comment: Why do you define `Occs` as `IQueryable` inside `RatesList`? Whats wrong with defining it as `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Hi - because I'm getting confused, I've been looking at this for a long time now - that's what I'm asking for help with.  But more so, how do I turn Occs and the occdesc and occdesc2 into the select list value and text items?  Thank you, Mark

Comment: If you have your `Occs` in `RatesList` defined as `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable` you can simply create an select list from it using `new SelectList(ratesList.Occs, "occdesc", "occdesc2");` where the last two parameters are the names of the properties that act as key and value for the drop-down.

Comment: Hi @Aschratt - thank you - can you let me know where I would put `new SelectList(ratesList.Occs, "occdesc", "occdesc2");` please?

Comment: It depends. I would store the select list within the view model directly and therefor the expression should get located where you instanciate your view model. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create editors for queries and thus you have to turn your `Occs`-Property into an `IEnumerable<Occ>`. Since you want to create a drop-down it's even better to prove a SelectList instead:

```
public class RatesList
{
    public SelectList Occs { get; set; }
    public string OccSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In your view, you can use the select list as data source for your drop down:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OccSelected, Model.Occs);
```

The selected value will be stored inside the `OccSelected` property. When you instanciate your view model, make sure to also initialize the select list:

```
var model = new RatesList()
{
    Occs = new SelectList(occsQuery.ToList(), "occdesc", "occdesc2")
}
```

Where the `occdesc` property acts as key and the `occdesc2` property acts as description for your drop-down items. `occsQuery` is what was your `IQueryable<Occ>` before and `ToList` ensures that it gets executed and represented as enumerable collection.